# Issues populating background image through JSON into list view items

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I have been trying to resolve this issue since a while, but my attempts so far have not been satisfactory.

In brief, I am trying to have a background image for each listview array of items generated from the JSON data. I have already set the url for the background image in JSON. The JSON function has already been configured, and hence I am already able to populate data into the application from an online source.

Just to show you a sample visualization. The background image would be shown similarly to the following:

http://www.mobile-patterns.com/?q=Hotel+Tonight+feed

but each background image item would refer to their respective JSON string.

I am really stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Below is my ListViewAdapter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    protected String list_item_bac;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView list_item_name;
        TextView country;
        TextView list_item_price;
        ImageView list_item_bac;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        RelativeLayout rootRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootRelativeLayout);

        new ImageDownloadTask(rootRelativeLayout,"http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php").execute();
        //rootRelativeLayout.setBackground(null);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        list_item_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
        country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        list_item_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_price);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        list_item_bac = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_bac);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        list_item_name.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_NAME));
        country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        list_item_price.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_PRICE));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_BAC), list_item_bac);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_NAME));

                intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));

                intent.putExtra("list_item_price",resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_PRICE));

                intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", resultp.get(MainActivity.LIST_ITEM_BAC));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
    AsyncTask<View,View,View> mytask= new AsyncTask<View,View,View>() {

        @Override
        protected View doInBackground(View... params) {
                    Bitmap img = imageLoader.loadImageSync(list_item_bac);

            return null;
        }
    };

    class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<View, View, View>
    {
        RelativeLayout mrelativelayout;
        String downloadUrl;
         Bitmap img;
        public ImageDownloadTask(RelativeLayout layout,String url)
        {

            mrelativelayout=layout;
            downloadUrl=url;
        }
        @Override
        protected View doInBackground(View... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img = imageLoader.loadImageSync(downloadUrl);
            return null;
        }
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), img);
                mrelativelayout.setBackground(d);
            }
    }
    }
```

Below is my JSON Function class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

The listview layout xml is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="7dp"
android:id="@+id/rootRelativeLayout"
android:paddingBottom="7dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:text="@string/countrylabel" 
    android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" 
    android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:text="@string/populationlabel" 
    android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/country"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="0.01"
    android:textColor="#f2f2f2"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_bac"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:alpha="0.8" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

If you require any other information that could assist you in assisting me, let me know.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Updated code with single item click

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.dooba.beta.Events_List;
import com.dooba.beta.R;
import com.dooba.beta.R.id;
import com.dooba.beta.R.layout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gvAnuncios;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> anuncios;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_anuncios);
        gvAnuncios = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_anuncios);
        anuncios = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        descargarAnuncios();

        //add interface ItemClickListener
        public interface ItemClickListener {


                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                        intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                        startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                    }

                }


                //catch in the second activity values ??that you use to
                long id_item = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id_item");
                int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id_item");

        //sorry, my english is low :)

        //remember add reference to id of the item from your json we service in adapter


            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return items.get(position).id; //<--your id from json

    }
        }}





    public void descargarAnuncios(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        //add object anuncio to arraylist anuncios
                        anuncios.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gvAnuncios.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),anuncios));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); //title item
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac")); //url image "http//:google.image.....jpg"
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to yours and solved using Volley and Picasso library. this is my code, and I hope I can help. I use a gridview, is almost equal.
https://mega.co.nz/#!3Z5SSTCR!PxG2SmPTFYwqY6RDfpU1RK8tS6hN9nBovGF8lCtUVoc

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped tremendously. I am now working on "single Item click". That is when a user click on a list item, it takes them a respective activity that populates more information about it.

Comment: OK. check this...    https://mega.co.nz/#!bBZh1IDI!MLDaNUOlOFe6ONYDeOVMEMIJUWcd74cf_TQKVwHitro

Comment: Thanks bro. Your support has been incredible. As a suggestion, we could try to work with caches such has memory and file to increase the speed and efficiency and hence make the experience more seamless for the user. The following link provides more information. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/  As for the single item code, you have kindly provided. I tried adding it, but encountered some issues I am having difficulty fixing. You can view the updated code with single item in my updated post

Comment: Hi I did the adaptation of your code, I worked on android 4.4.2, only imports and Volley Picasso library, then runs. for any questions, we are here :). 
Note: reduces the size of the images because it causes low memory.   https://mega.co.nz/#!icxjjR5D!0JIW-BAamLS2kKEfu7ESn3txkRDdevQ-aR84HoFE6nU

Comment: Thanks brother, your help has been tremendous.For file size, I have somehow resolved the issue by including an image upload system in the back end, where if the image size is too great, than it would be not upload. As for the new code you have kindly suggested, I seem to prefer your previous one. The issue is with adding the single item based around your previous suggestion with "add interface ItemClickListener" to activity. I have added that activity code under update in my initial post. It would be nice if there was a button in single item that would take user to a new activity when click.

Comment: I have same issue , I want to set the background of listView and I am using Volley adapter the link you have provide is not working ? Please help